# adding disk storage for windows server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

Is it possible to add external storage (or any other solution to increase disk storage) to windows server 2012, which is already running on PC. I am running out of space, and I would like the easiest solution so I would be able to store new data without deleting anything I collected yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add external storage just like any other Windows machine.  I would recommend you make sure to format the storage as NTFS and I would only put static data on it; no database or program files.

Comment: thanks man. but I would need to have database there, because I am collecting some data on server. so what do you suggest, how to extend storage which is almost full?

Comment: Databases tend to be very write-intensive, and a USB/eSATA/whatever bus isn't going to be able to handle this as well as an on-board SATA/SAS bus.  If you run a database there, performance is going to be be an issue.  The best thing you can do is back up everything, add more internal storage, and rebuild and restore your data.  If that is not an option, the only other thing I can suggest is to move any non-database files you can onto external storage to make room for the database on internal storage.